# Tag synonyms for pgAdmin

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I am in the process of cleaning up the mess around the tags for [pgadmin](/questions/tagged/pgadmin).

[pgadminiii](/questions/tagged/pgadminiii) and [pgadmin3](/questions/tagged/pgadmin3) all refer to the same thing. Internally we (pgAdmin developers) just speak of "pgAdmin" nowadays.

I managed to propose [pgadminiii](/questions/tagged/pgadminiii) as tag synonym, but could not do the same for [pgadmin3](/questions/tagged/pgadmin3). Got the error message:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators (click on
>   this box to dismiss)

However, `pgAdmin III` is not a reference to a specific version of the program. And, strictly, there is no `pgAdmin 3` at all. The precursors "pgAdmin I" and "pgAdmin II" are long forgotten. The switch to `pgAdmin III` marks the change to a different license and code base (from Visual Basic to C++) many years ago. The current version of [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) is 1.14.2.

Could an admin kindly lend a hand? [pgadmin](/questions/tagged/pgadmin) should be the master tag.

I have now added a [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pgadmin/info) and would appreciate assistance in cleaning up the aliases.

Disclosure: I am a (low activity nowadays) member of the dev team of pgAdmin.

Comment: There is currently a tag cleanup : http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315/179059. You should post your question here (as an answer) to get help ;)

Comment: @alain.janinm: Thanks, I tried my luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been cleaned up as part of [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012/130979#comment362951_130979).

Basically, [pgadminiii](/questions/tagged/pgadminiii) and [pgadmin3](/questions/tagged/pgadmin3) have been retagged [pgadmin](/questions/tagged/pgadmin).

I didn't add the synonyms, as [it was indicated that the version numbers were outdated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012/130979#comment362611_130979).  If you want specific version numbers (1.14.2) then we can add the tag for you, just give us a question and we'll put it on.

Note that we wouldn't make a synonym for it, because version numbers being a synonym generally doesn't work (sometimes there's no need for one, other times, you need *just* that version, etc.).

Comment: I don't see the need for version-specific tags for pgAdmin, given the low volume. The cleaned variants `pgadminiii` and `pgadmin3` weren't actual versions. Only pgAdmin should be used as I see it.

Comment: In addition, I went through all questions and unified the spelling to "pgAdmin" in all titles (plus cleaning the whole post while being at it). So people don't get the wrong idea ... Should be fixed for good now.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Much appreciated.  Did you flag/vote to close when the question was not up to standard?

Comment: No. There wasn't any outstanding trash. And most of them have a useful answer. So I improved questions rather than voting to close. But I guess I can use that somewhat more often.